# tarring find results on hp-ux

Tags: find, tar, hp-ux

```
$ find /tmp/a1
/tmp/a1
/tmp/a1/b2
/tmp/a1/b1
/tmp/a1/b1/x1
```

simply trying

```
find /tmp/a1 -exec tar -cvf dirall.tar {} \;
```

simply doesn't work

any help

Answer (score 3):

The command specified for `-exec` is run once for each file found.  As such, you're recreating dirall.tar every time the command is run.  Instead, you should pipe the output of find to tar.

```
find /tmp/a1 -print0 | tar --null -T- -cvf dirall.tar
```

Note that if you're simply using `find` to get a list of all the files under `/tmp/a1` and not doing any sort of filtering, it's much simpler to use `tar -cvf dirall.tar /tmp/a1`.

Comment: Or even tar -cvf \`find /tmp/a1\` now that I think about it :)

Actually, if you tar /tmp/a1, you get it all anyway. I might be misunderstanding the problem.

Comment: Yeah, I was just assuming that the `find` was actually more complex and that the question had been boiled down to a simple scenario.

Answer (score 1):

You're one character away from the solution. The `find` command's `exec` option will execute the command for *each file* found, so you should replace `-c` with `-r` to put `tar` into append mode. Each time `find` invokes it, it'll tack on one more file:

```
rm -f dirall.tar
find /tmp/a1 -exec tar -rvf dirall.tar {} \;
```

Comment: You can only specify one "function" option.  Here you have two -- `-c` and `-r`.  Drop the `-c` (and quote or escape the `{}`) and it should work.

Comment: Thanks for catching the typo -- I should have tried the command first. I've edited the answer to remove the -c option. Also, no need to escape the {} in a Bourne-based shell.

Answer (score 0):

I'd think something like "find /tmp/a1 | xargs tar cvf foo.tar" would work. But make sure you have backups first!

Answer (score 0):

Does hpux have cpio ? 
That will take a list of files on stdin and some versions
will write output in tar format.